# How to redirect output when running a exe through cygstart command .

Tags: node.js, cmd, cygwin

I am running a node generated exe binary in cgywin . But it gives error

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/804  -- checkout the last comment.

**It works fine in windows cmd , so I am using cygstart command . 
But the issue is I cant get the logs after running cygstart .**

> cygstart someee.exe arguments > output.txt

This also doesn't gives output in output.txt

Can anyone help me out .

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. You have to do some quoting and escaping to that the correct information gets passed to ShellExecute.

```
cygstart bash -c \"ls \> ls.out \"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like

```
cygstart.exe cmd /C "node index.js > output"
```

Then I can use `tailf output` to show the log.

The temporary cmd prompt is annoying and I'm looking for something better.